How to ensure a CSS animation runs on an component before the item is removed from the array?
I am trying to figure out a way to have an element fade out in the browser before it is removed from the array.
In my parent component, I have some code like this:

function Items() {
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);
    const [removeItem, setRemoveItem] = useState(null);
    
    useEffect(() => {
        //Fetch data from API and update setData with response.
        setData(response.json());
    }, []);

    return (
        <div className="items">
                {data.length > 0 &&
                    data.map((item) => {
                        return(
                            <Item 
                                item={ item } 
                                data={ data } 
                                setData={ setData } 
                                setRemoveItem={ setRemoveItem } 
                                addClass={ item.id === removeItem ? ' item--fadeout' : '' }
                                key={ item.id } 
                            />
                        )
                    })
                }
        </div>
     )
}

export default Items;

In my Item component, I have the following code:
function Item({ item, data, setData, setRemoveItem, addClass }) {

    useEffect(() => {
        const endTime = new Date(item.endTime);
        const itemID = item.id;

        const timeCheck = (endTime, itemID) => {

            let time = new Date();
    
            let ending = Math.floor(parseInt(endTime) - (time.getTime()/1000));
            let minutes = Math.floor(ending / 60);
            let seconds = ending % 60;
            
            if (minutes <= 0 && seconds < 0) {
                setRemoveItem(itemID);
                setData(data.filter(item => item.id !== itemID));
            }
        }

        const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
            timeCheck(endTime.getTime()/1000, itemID)
        }, 1000);

        return () => clearInterval(intervalId);
    }, [item, data, setData, setRemoveItem]);


return(
        <div className={`item${addClass}`}>
            { item.title } 
        </div>
    )
}

export default Item;

For good measure, my SCSS:
.item {

    border-bottom: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
    overflow: hidden;
    clear: both;

    &--fadeout {
        -webkit-animation: fadeout 0.3s linear forwards;
        animation: fadeout 0.3s linear forwards;
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeout {
    0% {
        opacity: 1;
        display: block;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0;
        display: none;
    }
}

@keyframes fadeout {
    0% {
        opacity: 1;
        display: block;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0;
        display: none;
    }
}

If I remove the setData in my Item component logic, then the item--fade class is added to the item and fades out as expected. If I leave the setData state in there, then the data is just removed from the object and no css animation is triggered.
Any ideas on what logic I have out of place to both trigger the animation and then remove the data state?

You could use something like https://headlessui.com/ to achieve this without building all the custom animation stuff yourself.

Thanks for the response and recommendation. I will check it out. My fear is more of a race condition in my logic than faulty animation logic, but maybe the library has some built in mechanics to circumvent that.
